# how can i achieve this 100% height effect with divs rather than tables in pure css?

Tags: css

[alt text http://1updesign.org/uploads/kambe.png](http://1updesign.org/uploads/kambe.png)

Answer (score 2):

I usually create a containing div (which emulates a table row), and then divs for the specific columns (emulates table data).

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left-column column"></div>
    <div class="right-column column"></div>
</div>
```

Then make the container relatively positioned:

```
.container { position: relative }
```

This allows absolutely positioned elements within the container. Then we can use some of the benefits of absolute positioning to stretch the column divs:

```
.column { position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; }
```

Then you will want to put the left column on the left and the right column on the right:

```
.left-column { left: 0; }
.right-column { right: 0; }
```

The rest (styling) is up to you, I think that should do it.

## Edit: Proof Of Concept

I wrote this proof of concept code as follows:

```
<html>
    <head>

        <style type="text/css">
            .container { height: 200px; width: 200px; position: relative; border: 5px solid red; }
            .left-column { width: 100px; background-color: blue; left: 0; }
            .right-column { width: 100px; background-color: yellow; right: 0; }
            .column { position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="left-column column"></div>
            <div class="right-column column"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Which renders as:

[image]

I hope that helps.

Comment: I was expecting a tables vs. CSS firestorm!

Answer (score 1):

An excellent example here that shows how to do full and equal height columns in a css fashion.

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-5-column.htm